# Pygame won't play audio, but only when running as a daemon

Tags: python, audio, pygame, raspberry-pi, daemon

A bit of background: I have a Raspberry Pi 3b running Raspbian(Debian) 9.11. This original Pi runs a Python 3 script that captures text input from a handheld scanner and sends it into a MySQL database, and then plays a wav file so the employees scanning know it was successful. I daemonized this process so it was easier to restart (sometimes the scanners lose sync with their USB dongles). The main line in the daemon file is this

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/scanner.py
```

I had to change the process slightly for a new instance I was asked to create, so I loaded Raspbian 10.4 (latest) onto another Pi 3b and moved everything over with only the slight tweak that it now inserts to a local Maria DB (MySQL basically). Daemon runs just fine... except that no audio plays (but the DB insert still happens). What's really weird is when I load it in Thonny, it plays the file just fine. There's nothing in the syslog indicating Python or Pygame are generating any errors.

The relevant code here (abbreviated) is

```
import pygame.mixer
# sets up sound
pygame.mixer.init()
goodscan = pygame.mixer.Sound('/home/pi/Desktop/goodscan.wav')
duplicatescan = pygame.mixer.Sound('/home/pi/Desktop/duplicateScan.wav')
badscan = pygame.mixer.Sound('/home/pi/Desktop/badScan.wav')

#function that the USB listener calls
def scan(scanner):
    #some scanner processing codes here
    if prevScan == x:
        duplicatescan.play()
        print("Duplicate Scan")
        continue;
                 
     else:
        splits = x.split('-')
        if(len(splits) < 3):
            print("No prefix provided")
            #write to error log
            badscan.play();
            continue;
        prefix = splits[0][0] + splits[0][1]
        po = splits[1] + '-' + splits[2]
        scanner_number = splits[0][2] + splits[0][3]
        polist.extend([po, prefixes[prefix], scanner_number])
        goodscan.play()
        
        #DB insert (this always works)                
        scans = {
           "timestamp": time_str,
           "ponum": x,
           "status": polist[1],
           "scanner": polist[2]
        }
        statusUpdate.databaseUpdate(polist)
```

How can I debug why this isn't working in daemon mode?

Comment: Is the daemon running as the same user / with the same privileges, to audio-out?

Comment: When the daemon runs, it's running as root. But I noticed Thonny runs under the pi user. Theoretically root should have privs to the audio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this is related to the shift from the Raspberry Pi OS to Linux kernel 5.4 (the older Pi is running kernel 4.19). I used pip to upgrade to Pygame 1.9.6, which added this error to the syslog when stopping or restarting the service

> Sep  3 08:40:46 raspberrypi kernel: [164439.999815] bcm2835_audio bcm2835_audio: failed to close VCHI service connection (status=1)

Kingsley asked in a comment what user this runs under and the answer was root (I never specified a user in the system service file). I noted, however, that Thonny runs under the "pi" user. I figured giving that a shot might work, so I added

```
User=pi
```

to my service file and now Pygame audio works again in the service.